# Can specific metaphors be interpreted or meant to be interpreted in a vaguer and more general way?

Tags: poetry, metaphor

> A boat of heaven shed roses.

A boat of heaven is a symbol of the female genitalia. Shedding roses means she bled and lost her virginity, but can we still use the phrase to simply mean "loss of innocence" without implying that the woman had sex or lost her virginity? Is it something acceptable?

> The flowery bronze slit of the castle was gaped open

Similarly, can we use "the vagina was gaped open" to imply loss of innocence without sex?

Comment: Wow.. You know, if you hadn't said what they supposedly meant, I never would have guessed. I parsed "A boat of heaven shed roses" as "a boat containing roses shed from heaven".

Comment: Whatever it means you can't write *The flowery bronze slit of the castle was gaped open* you'd have to change it to *The flowery bronze slit of the castle gaped open* or something else entirely.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you writing? Why do you want to use these metaphors? There are many kinds of innocence and many ways to express loss of innocence, and your metaphors are certainly not the only way or in many situations the best way. If you're a good enough writer, you certainly can use romantic love and sexual experience as a metaphor for other kinds of experience (a lot of religious writing uses romantic love and marriage as metaphors for closeness to or acceptance of God). But it's impossible to know if this is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If your metaphor is for a woman having sex for the first time, then you can expect your reader to assume you meant she had sex.

‘Losing virginity’ does have a long-standing association with loss of innocence, so if a reader understands your examples to be metaphors for a woman’s sexual activity, then they may then move from ‘losing virginity’ to thinking about loss of innocence generally. But she still had sex.

Unsolicited advice #1:

The phrase ‘losing virginity’ and the association of having sex for the first time with ‘loss of innocence’ is problematic for many reasons, including the way it is used as a measure of a woman’s worth, and its inherent heteronormativity (google ‘stop saying losing virginity’ for a lot of pages on the matter). If these metaphors are from your own writing, please consider using a different metaphor entirely.

Unsolicited advice #2:

I don’t think these metaphors work.

> A boat of heaven shed roses.

You explain the shedding roses as bleeding and having sex for the first time. I could maybe get behind the bleeding if I picture a boat with red roses spilling out, but it’s another damaging assumption that bleeding always happens when having sex for the first time.

> The flowery bronze slit of the castle was gaped open

I’m struggling to imagine a castle with a flowery bronze slit – is it a window with a window box?  Also, I don’t think I’d ever refer to a vagina as ‘gaping open’, unless I was talking about having a smear test and it’s literally being jacked open with a speculum.